# SQL Query to Add Values from Column X for Every Entry That Has Y

Tags: sql, filter, sum, row

I need to write a query that is going to calculate the sum of one column depending on the values of another.  Basically I need to get the sum of a certain drug administered for each patient in one of my DB's tables.  My table has an account number column (x), drug ID column (y) and an amount administered column (z).  The thing is there can be multiple rows for each account number so what I need to do is pull the total amount of that drug administered for each patient account number.  So in essence I need a query that will return the sum of z for for every x with a where clause at the end using column y.  I hope I am explaining this clearly because thinking about it confuses me!  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple GROUP BY query, I'm not sure what's confusing you.

```
SELECT x, SUM(z) total_z
FROM table
WHERE y = 123
GROUP BY x
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  I'm still learning SQL and I've never used the SUM function before.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT x, y, sum(z)
FROM t
GROUP by x, y
```